# How to tell the sizes of files and folders, sorted, and in MB, GB, instead of a long integer?

Tags: shell, command-line, disk-usage, sort

On a Mac, using Bash, I tend to do

```
du -sh *
```

to tell the sizes of files and folders in the current directory, in MB and GB.  But if I want to sort them by the sizes, I might do

```
du -sh * | sort -g
```

and it won't work well, because the `M` and `G` is not taken into account (so 44MB might be thought to be larger than 20GB, because 44 is greater than 20).

Is there a way not to write a program and just use UNIX commands and/or a Bash function to do that?

If I care about the files and folders that are in the `GB` range, I can do:

```
du -sh * | egrep "^\s*\d+(.\d+)?G\s" | sort -g
```

and it will show

```
2.6G    ski video clips
7.6G    trip 2012.mp4
 12G    trip photos
```

but if `TB` or `MB` is to be considered, then the above will not work.  Is there a way to do this more generally using UNIX / Mac OS X commands?

Comment: Does your sort command have a `-h` option? It's the same as du's -h

Comment: it says invalid options (on OS X Yosemite).  If there is, you would do `du -sh * | sort -gh` ?

Comment: This doesn't strictly answer your question, but I usually use `du -sk * | sort -n` which lists the sizes in kilobytes. I find that easier to read than raw bytes.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12927/list-the-size-in-human-readable-form-of-all-sub-folders-from-the-current-location says:

```
du -ks $(ls -d */) | sort -nr | cut -f2 | xargs -d '\n' du -sh 2> /dev/null
```

This is tested on a Mac and only runs `du` once. It has the minor error that 1K=1000 and not 1024:

```
du -sk * | sort -n | perl -pe '@SI=qw(K M G T P); s:^(\d+?)((\d\d\d)*)\s:$1.$SI[((length $2)/3)]."\t":e'
```

Comment: the above line doesn't work on the Mac...

Comment: hm... and I think this solution uses 2 passes of `du`... maybe better if it can be 1 pass.  But thanks for the commandlinefu.com pointer

Comment: In practice the second pass is often done in cache: Size data is not very big so you have to have a small cache for it not to fit.